# Subquery in the WHERE clause exercise

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a migration table with attributes (name, departure year) and a stork table with attributes(name, year of birth). I want to write a query giving the names of all storks that migrated before the birth of the youngest stork which is 2002 (using the migration table in the main query and the Stork table in a sub-request of the WHERE clause). N.B: Not allowed to use a clause such as WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, LIMIT, unless it is necessary/mandatory

```
Migration table
Name        DEPARTURE YEAR   
Annamarie   2001   
Felix       2002
Annamarie   2003
Felix       2004
Jonas       2001

Stork table
Name       YEAROFBIRTH
Annamarie   1998
Felix       1999
Max         2000
Jonas       2001
Christina   2002
```

Using the DISTINCT operator gives the desired result with 15 names, removing the DISTINCT operator gives me 25 names with duplicates

```
SELECT DISTINCT migration.NAME
FROM migration
WHERE migration.DEPARTUREYEAR IN(SELECT stork.YEAROFBIRTH
FROM stork
WHERE stork.YEAROFBIRTH <2002)
```

I expect to obtain the 15 names without using the DISTINCT operator

Comment: Is there some requirement that you use a subquery? While that query does not look right, you should not be getting duplicates unless `migration` itself has duplicates; and if it does, DISTINCT is really your only option (short of abusing GROUP BY).

Comment: so what exactly is the question?

Comment: From your examples, it seems Migration table has duplicate names.  Do you want to    compare with the first or last date of migration?  If this is an class exercise, I would think that the point is to find the year of birth for the youngest stork with a subquery, not by hard-coding 2002.

Answer (score 1):

Just going by the desired result, and your example's use of the literal year; this should be all you need.

```
SELECT DISTINCT migration.NAME
FROM migration
WHERE migration.DEPARTUREYEAR < 2002
;
```

However, if you want to not use a literal year, the subquery can be used to determine it like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT migration.NAME
FROM migration
WHERE migration.DEPARTUREYEAR < (SELECT MAX(stork.YEAROFBIRTH) FROM stork)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT NAME -- You can apply DISTINCT if required 
FROM Migration
WHERE Name IN (
    SELECT Name FROM Stork
    WHERE YEAROFBIRTH < 2002
)
```

Comment: (1) It's not MSSQL, (2) that query just gets any stork born before 2002 that has ever migrated, even if that stork migrated in 2003.